# Bootstrap 3 grid with no gap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a 2 column grid, with literally a 50% with no margins or padding.

How do I achieve this with Bootstrap 3 I tried this but end up with negative margins at tablet/desktop break points:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 offset-0">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 offset-0">Col 2</div>
    </div>
</diV>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.row > * {
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
.row :first-child {
    background: red;
}
.offset-0 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

DEMO -
http://jsfiddle.net/pjBzY/

Comment: yes there are negative margins but still the content is filling 100% of the container

Comment: I updated the fiddle without the text align center so that you can better see what the issue is

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24270137/1828879

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grid system in Bootstrap 3 requires a bit of a lateral shift in your thinking from Bootstrap 2.  A column in BS2 (`col-*`) is NOT synonymous with a column in BS3 (`col-sm-*`, etc), but there is a way to achieve the same result.

Check out this update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjBzY/22/ (code copied below).

First of all, you don't need to specify a col for each screen size if you want 50/50 columns at all sizes. `col-sm-6` applies not only to small screens, but also medium and large, meaning `class="col-sm-6 col-md-6"` is redundant (the benefit comes in if you want to change the column widths at different size screens, such as `col-sm-6 col-md-8`).

As for the margins issue, the negative margins provide a way to align blocks of text in a more flexible way than was possible in BS2.  You'll notice in the jsfiddle, the text in the first column aligns visually with the text in the paragraph outside the `row` -- except at "xs" window sizes, where the columns aren't applied.

If you need behavior closer to what you had in BS2, where there is padding between each column and there are no visual negative margins, you will need to add an inner-div to each column.  See the `inner-content` in my jsfiddle.  Put something like this in each column, and they will behave the way old `col-*` elements did in BS2.

---

jsfiddle HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="other-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse aliquam sed sem nec viverra. Phasellus fringilla metus vitae libero posuere mattis. Integer sit amet tincidunt felis. Maecenas et pharetra leo. Etiam venenatis purus et nibh laoreet blandit.</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 my-column">
            Col 1
            <p class="inner-content">Inner content - THIS element is more synonymous with a Bootstrap 2 col-*.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 my-column">
            Col 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.row {
    border: blue 1px solid;
}
.my-column {
    background-color: green;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.my-column:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}

.inner-content {
    background: #eee;
    border: #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Nicely explained but the issue was the opposite to the solutions you have provided. I want a simple grid with no gaps or negative margins. Then if padding is needed it can easily be added inside the cols if required.

Answer (score 58):

Another option would be to create your own special CSS class for whenever you want to apply the "gutterless" columns..

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">Col 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.no-gutter [class*="-6"] {
    padding-left:0;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/73960

Comment: This example shows what you have here doesn't really work, you need to remove the negative margin from row: http://www.bootply.com/132839

Comment: This will only work for 6 column grids, best to use class*="col-" to work for all.

Answer (score 28):

I always add this style to my Bootstrap LESS / SASS:

```
.row-no-padding {
  [class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

Then in the HTML you can write:

```
<div class="row row-no-padding">
```

Comment: This only worked for me after I removed the outer `{}`. I like this solution better because it selects by `col` keyword, rather than a specific column width.

Comment: Just so you know : the code provided is not CSS, it's LESS, that is why you had to remove the outer {}

Answer (score 8):

You'd need to override the negative margins from the `.row` in large screens either directly or with a custom class

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .row {
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjBzY/4/embedded/result/)**

Comment: This could potentially break other scripts which might require the margin. The margin is useful in some cases but there also needs to be a way of removing it

Comment: you can always use a custom class (like you did in your answer)

Answer (score 5):

I am sure there must be a way of doing this without writing my own CSS, its crazy I have to overwrite the margin and padding, all I wanted was a 2 column grid.

```
.row-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.row-offset-0 > * {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KxCkD/

Comment: I guess Bootstrap believes you would normally want the padding between columns (so content doesn't end up touching) and therefore yours is more of a custom need, one that you can meet by adding a couple extra rules to your CSS, which I don't think it's that bad

Comment: Why not create a div class with `width:50%`? That's all you need! A class with a single property.

Comment: @koala_dev I just think it should be the other way round, default no padding and only add it if you need it

Comment: @edsioufi I may wish to increase the number of columns

Answer (score 4):

Generalizing on martinedwards and others' ideas, you can glue a bunch of columns together (not just a pair) by adjusting padding of even and odd column children. Adding this definition of a class, `.no-gutter`, and placing it on your `.row` element

```
.row.no-gutter > [class*='col-']:nth-child(2n+1) {
    padding-right: 0;
 } 

.row.no-gutter > [class*='col-']:nth-child(2n) {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Or in SCSS:

```
.no-gutter  {
    > [class*='col-'] {
        &:nth-child(2n+1) {
            padding-right: 0;
        }
        &:nth-child(2n) {
            padding-left: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer should get more attention!

Answer (score 3):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32876993) given by [@yuvilio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462002/yuvilio) works well for two columns but, for more than two, [this](http://codepen.io/JulienMelissas/pen/jEpbEY) from [here](http://julienmelissas.com/no-gutter-column-trick-for-bootstrap) might be a better solution. In summary:

```
.row.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;

  & > [class^="col-"],
  & > [class*=" col-"] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for linking to my article :)

Answer (score 1):

Use "clearfix" instead of "row". It does the exact same except it doesn't have a negative margin. Step through the "row" usage and you'll see that's the only difference.

Answer (score 0):

The more powerful (and 100% fluid) Bootstrap 3 grid now comes in 3 sizes. Tiny (for smartphones .col-*), Small (for tablets .col-sm-*) and Large (for laptops/desktops .col-lg-*). The 3 grid sizes enable you to control grid behavior on different devices (desktop, tablet, smartphone, etc..).

Unlike 2.x, Bootstrap 3 does not provide a fixed (pixel-based) grid. While a fixed-width layout can still be acheived using a simple custom wrapper, there is now only one percentage-based (fluid) grid. The .container and .row classes are now fluid by default, so don't use .row-fluid or .container-fluid anymore in your 3.x markup.

[Source](http://www.bootply.com/migrate-to-bootstrap-3)

Comment: we're dealing with Bootstrap 3 here, there is no `row-fluid` anymore

Comment: Sorry I don't see the "3" in question, I have edit my answer to use Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can use bellow class.

```css
.nopadmar {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 nopadmar">Your Content<div>
       <div class="col-md-6 nopadmar">Your Content<div>
  </div>
</div>
```