# Unwanted empty space in 3 column grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this grid which has to take up the full width of the container, but it keeps adding unwanted space on the left and right sides. I added a border around the areas: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDgib.png

There is a container wrapper div and 3 divs with col-lg-4.

The only thing that works so far is to set a negative margin on the left block, which is not ideal I assume.

How to make sure the full width is consumed?

Answer (score 3):

If you are compiling Bootstrap from `less` source, simple change the `@grid-gutter-width` variable in `variables.less` to the value `0`. It is distributed with the default value of `30px`.

**Do not** just modify the `css` files. There are 15 places in the `less` source where `@grid-gutter-width` is referenced, and those are then referenced in very many more places - in other words, the variable has far-reaching effects. Just modifying the compiled `css` files will inevitably leave the overall styling in a bad state.

Comment: That is simple but brilliant. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

By default all "col" divs have 15px padding on the left and right. You will want to change:

```
.col-lg-4 {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    }
```

to

```
.col-lg-4 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    }
```

Comment: I agree with @TimothyShields that it's best to not modify CSS, you could create a new class like `col-lg-4-no-padding` but don't change your core CSS classes

Comment: I completely agree as well. I should have been more clear as to say create the same class in your own style file (which is run after bootstrap.css), or you could certainly give it it's own class like Dan suggested. You would need to make sure to copy the attributes of col-lg-4 when duplicated though. Overriding the code in your own style file is typically cleaner and easier.

Comment: @user3711852 Even if you did that, all of the other Bootstrap styling would now be inconsistent with your modification. `@grid-gutter-width` is used in all kinds of margin, padding, spacing, sizing, and positioning computations. If you modify just those two properties of the `.col-lg-4` class - even in a separate file, which is cleaner - those other measures will still all visually mismatch.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for clarifying @TimothyShields. That is much more consistent.