# Add place for handwriting with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <p class="classPadBottom0">Credit Card Number:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 ClsUnderline ClassPad0">
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1">
                    <p class="classPadBottom0">Exp. Date:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 ClsUnderline">
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qyk1nbb5/)**

I have create small example what i have now. It's like 2 labels and place for handwriting. But it isn't very responsive and have too much space between label and handwriting place.

Is there another way to add such space?

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202240/bootstrap-3-grid-with-no-gap

Comment: Answer: Yes there is. Seriously, why do you think it's not 'responsible'?

Comment: @Peter, cause under that part that i showed in example, i have similar one but with another text. So it depands on length of text.

Comment: I assume "responsible" is meant to be **"responsive"** ?

Comment: @Paulie_D, ooops, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this - https://jsfiddle.net/qyk1nbb5/2/

I have made use of definition lists to provide you with a clean responsive solution for displaying the label & value. Also using the standard WordPress column structure.

There is a small amount of CSS involved to convert the form items to just have an underline.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt><label for="card_number">Credit Card Number:</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" class="form-control text-line" id="card_number" name="card_number" /></dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt><label for="card_expiry">Exp Date:</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" class="form-control text-line" id="card_expiry" name="card_expiry" /></dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
DT {
    line-height: 34px;
}

INPUT.text-line {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888888;

    box-shadow: none;
    -o-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;

    border-radius: 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
```

I hope this answers your question and gives you a working solution.

You should also perhaps have a read about inline forms - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Also, definition lists for your reference - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#description

Comment: Yes, it looks nice. Just one note - i don't need textbox for input. I generate this page as pdf, then user must write at some places what he/she want.

Comment: I use css for "INPUT.text-line" on :focus and now it looks as what i want. Thanks